# gcloud usage 101 for ssh

Tags: networking, server, ssh, java, cloud

How do I install and use [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/)?  In the [context of](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#sshingcloud):

> Connecting to Linux Instances
>
> This guide shows you how to connect to Linux instances using common
>   SSH tools on Linux, OSX, and Windows workstations. If you need to
>   connect to a Windows instance, connect using RDP instead.
>
> The easiest way to connect to a Linux instance on Compute Engine is to
>   connect from your browser or connect using the gcloud tool.

How do I install the `gcloud` tool?

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ apt-cache search gcloud
golang-github-jacobsa-gcloud-dev - convenience wrapper around google cloud platform APIs
libhtml-tagcloud-perl - module for generating HTML indexes of popular tags
tagcloud - Visualize tagged notes as a cloud
thufir@doge:~$
```

I see that there's a [Java client library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/) for this API, but isn't that overkill for the purpose of connecting to a Linux instance through `ssh`?

In order to use `gcloud` I have to use a client library?  I'm not understanding at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Google's site](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads#apt-get), here are the steps to install `gcloud` on Debian based systems

You may need to install `curl`

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

> Create an environment variable for the correct distribution
>
> ```
> export CLOUD_SDK_REPO="cloud-sdk-$(lsb_release -c -s)"
> ```
>
> Add the Cloud SDK distribution URI as a package source
>
> ```
> echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt $CLOUD_SDK_REPO main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
> ```
>
> Import the Google Cloud public key
>
> ```
> curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
> ```
>
> Update and install the Cloud SDK
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk
> ```
>
> Run gcloud init to get started
>
> ```
> gcloud init
> ```